# IntelliJ IDEA CreativeProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Out of the blue, IntelliJ produced the following error:

> Error:Cannot run program "D:\Java\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\jurem.IdeaIC2016.3\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

The code I'm running is a simple "HelloWorld":

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine yesterday, not sure why it suddenly stopped working. Would be great if someone has any clues to what could be wrong and how to solve this.

Comment: Reinstall Java. If that doesn't fix it, reinstall IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Garrison , that solved the issue